# Using REGEX in notepad++ to manipulate a list

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of numbers in notepad++ from 0 to 250. The list looks like this:

```
==0
==1
==2
==3
==4
==5
==6
==7
==8
==9
==10
==11
==12
==13
...
```

I'm trying to use a regular expression to convert my list as follows:

```
0==0
1==1
2==2
3==3
4==4
5==5
6==6
7==7
8==8
9==9
10==10
11==11
12==12
13==13
```

Any idea how I can get the desired result?

Comment: I started with 1,2,3,...250, then I did "/n" replace with == and now I'm stuck as I can't remember how to duplicate the number of the find param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Replace All

Find what: `==(\d+)`

Replace with `$1==$1`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! (will accept answer post time limit restriction)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this would work in Notepad++, but this would work in vi:

```
:1,$s/==\(.*\)/\1==\1/
```

so search for

```
==\(.*\)
```

and replace with

```
\1==\1
```

but you may need to adjust for Notepad++ syntax